# Crash on UInt64 bitwise operation in Swift

Tags: swift, bit-manipulation

I need to execute this function to get the lsb from an unsigned 64 bit integer but the operation fails. I'm not very good at bitwise operations; could someone give me a hand?

```
func lsb(id: UInt64) -> UInt64 {
    return UInt64(Int64(id) & -Int64(id))
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a message with the crash?

Comment: Is there a parameter called "id" missing?

Comment: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

Comment: @swdev Sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: So, the problem is integer overflow, right? You could use the `&-` operator to subtract from zero with wrapping to prevent an overflow error there

Comment: Could you please show me how? This topic is like chinese to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to avoid overflow in 3 types of operations:

- UInt64 to Int64
- negation
- Int64 to UInt64

All above changed to overflow-free operations, your code becomes as:

```
func lsb(id: UInt64) -> UInt64 {
    return UInt64(bitPattern: Int64(bitPattern: id) & (0 &- Int64(bitPattern: id)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the LSB you can simply do:

```
func lsb() -> UInt64 {
    return UInt64(UInt64(id) & UInt64(0x0000000000000001))
}
```

The result will be a UInt64 with only the LSB.

Comment: Yes OP used confusing terminology there, he's isolating the lowest set bit, not the lsb.

Comment: @harold It is possible. I found this piece of code inside a bigger framework I'm trying to fix...

Comment: Anyway: Binary operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int64' and 'UInt64' @Matan

Comment: @lucamegh - Thanks I fixed that